# Set theory $(A\oplus B)' = A'\oplus B = A \oplus B'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've stuck with this equation. Did few transformation but it doesn't help.

$$(A \oplus B)' = (A\,\setminus\, B) ∪ (B\,\setminus\, A) = A ∩ B' ∪ B ∩ A'$$

$$A' \oplus B = (A'\,\setminus\, B) ∪ (B\,\setminus\, A') = A' ∩ B' ∪ A ∩ B$$

Any idea how to prove this? Thanks.

P.S. Here $\oplus$ denotes the symmetric difference and $A'$ is the complement of $A$.

Comment: Specify the notation, please. What does $A+B$ mean here and what does $A'$ mean?

Comment: Yeap, sorry. 
$+$ mean symmetric difference. 
And $A ∪ A'$ = universe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$(A \oplus B)' = [(A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)]'= [(A \cap B') \cup (B \cap A')]'\\
= [(A \cap B')' \cap (B \cap A')']
= (A' \cup B) \cap (B' \cup A)=(A' \cap B') \cup (A \cap B).$$
On the other hand
$$A' \oplus B=(A'\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A')=(A'\cap B') \cup (B\cap A),$$
and in a similar way
$$A \oplus B'=(A\setminus B') \cup (B'\setminus A)=(A\cap B) \cup (B'\cap A').$$

Comment: $(A′∪B)∩(B′∪A)=(A′∩B′)∪(A∩B)$ I don't understand this step, can you please clarify?

Comment: I use De Morgan $(A\cap B)'=A'\cup B'$.

Comment: @Dmitriy Filipenko Any further doubt?